# MySQL INSERT SELECT WHERE race condition

Tags: mysql, concurrency, innodb, race-condition

I'm working on a ticketing system where users escrow a large amount of tickets at once (basically all tickets that are not out of stock) before claiming them. These tickets that shown to the user and they can select whichever ticket they want to claim.

This escrow system could introduce race conditions if two users try to escrow the same tickets at the same time and there aren't enough tickets, as in:

Tickets left: 1

User A hits the page, checks number of tickets left. 1 ticket left
User B hits the page, checks number of tickets left. 1 ticket left

Since they both have a ticket left they would both escrow the ticket, making tickets left -1.

I'd like to avoid locking if at all possible and am wondering if a statement with subqueries like

```
INSERT INTO ticket_escrows (`ticket`,`count`) 
SELECT ticket,tickets_per_escrow FROM tickets WHERE tickets.total > (
    COALESCE(
        SELECT SUM(ticket_escrows.count) FROM ticket_escrows 
        WHERE ticket_escrows.ticket = tickets.id
        AND ticket_escrows.valid = 1
    ,0)
    +
    COALESCE(
        SELECT SUM(ticket_claims.count) 
        FROM ticket_claims
        WHERE ticket_claims.ticket = tickets.id
    ,0)
)
```

will be atomic and allow me to prevent race conditions without locking.

Specifically I'm wondering if the above query will prevent the following from happening:

```
Max tickets: 50 Claimed/Escrowed tickets: 49
T1: start tx -> sums ticket escrows --> 40
T2: start tx -> sums ticket escrows --> 40
T1: sums ticket claims --> 9
T2: sums ticket claims --> 9
T1: Inserts new escrow since there is 1 ticket left --> 0 tickets left
T2: Inserts new escrow since there is 1 ticket left --> -1 tickets left
```

I'm using InnoDB.

Comment: "*I'd like to avoid locking if at all possible*" - why?  Even if the statement is atomic (I think it may depend on your isolation level), its atomicity will be enforced using locks...

Comment: You should be locking the rows for UserA, so when UserB's query hit the table it waits for the `INSERT` to finish and get correct numbar of tickets, which is 0.

Comment: Shouldn't there be `SELECT id,ticket_per_escrow` in the first subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To answer your question "if a statement with subqueries ... will be atomic":** In your case, yes.

It will be atomic only when enclosed in a transaction. Since you state you're using InnoDB, the query even with subqueries is an SQL statement and as such executed in a transaction. Quoting the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-transaction-model.html):

> In InnoDB, all user activity occurs inside a transaction. If autocommit mode is enabled, each SQL statement forms a single transaction on its own.
>
> ...If a statement returns an error, the commit or rollback behavior depends on the error.

Also, [isolations levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Isolation_levels) matter.

> In terms of the SQL:1992 transaction isolation levels, the default InnoDB level is REPEATABLE READ

REPEATABLE READ  *may not be enough* for you, depending on the logic of your program. It prevents transactions from writing data that was read by another transaction until the reading transaction completes, [phantom reads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Phantom_reads) are possible, however. Check [SET TRANSACTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-transaction.html)  for a way how to change the isolation level.

---

**To answer your second question "if the above query will prevent the following from happening ...":** In a transaction with the SERIALIZABLE isolation level it cannot happen. I believe the default level should be safe as well in your case (supposing `tickets.total` doesn't change), but I'd prefer having it confirmed by someone.

Answer (score 1):

You have really left a lot of information out about how you want this to work, which is why you haven't gotten more/better answers.

Ticketing is a matter of trade-offs.  If you show someone there are 10 tickets available, either you immediately make all 10 tickets unavailable for everyone else (which is bad for everyone else) or your don't, which means that person could potentially order a ticket that someone else snapped up while they were deciding which ticket to take.   An "escrow" system doesn't really help matters, as it just moves the problem from which tickets to purchase to which tickets to escrow.

During the period where you are not locking everyone else out, the best practice is to craft your SQL in such a way that updates or inserts will fail if someone else has modified the data while you were working on it.  This can be as simple as incrementing a counter in the row every time the row is changed and using that counter (plus the primary key) in the WHERE clause of the UPDATE statement.  If the counter changed, then the update fails and you know you've lost the race.

I don't understand what you want to have happen or your data structures enough to give you much more advice.

Comment: Absolutely. The problem is not really a technical issue, but rather a business decision.

Comment: @YaK, the immediate problem is that the OP did not specify what business decision he is trying to implement. What is the meaning of escrowing tickets if someone else can snatch them while you have them escrowed?

Comment: Yes, what I meant is that this business decision needs to be taken, then the technical response will become obvious (and probably straightforward). My intention was to agree with you, sorry if this wasn't clear.